# How can I force text to "normal" (not bold) using css?

Tags: html, css

I have a class that I'm using to make some text navy and large:

```
.sectiontext {
    color: navy !important;
    font-size: large;
}
```

I apply it to elements like so:

```
<label class="sectiontext">Select a Unit</label>
. . .
<h4 class="sectiontext">Specify Recipients</h4>
```

The problem is that when I apply it to a label, it makes that text bold. I tried adding the following line to the sectiontext class:

```
font-weight: normal !important;
```

...but it makes no difference; I don't want to use "h4" instead of "label" for some bits of text because h4 always contains a "line break"; I wnat to be able to use this text style prior to a "select" element and several checkboxes, too, and thus not have the text "break"

But even with the "!important" added to the sectiontext class, the text remains bold. For example, compare the "Select a Unit" and "Select Report[s]" labels here with the H4 "Specify Recipients" and "Generate and Email Report" text:

[image]

What can I do to have a label that is not bold?

### UPDATE

The only custom CSS I have is:

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: lightyellow;
}

/* Set padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
.body-content {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

/* Override the default bootstrap behavior where horizontal description lists 
   will truncate terms that are too long to fit in the left column 
*/
.dl-horizontal dt {
    white-space: normal;
}

/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}

.containerforplatypus {
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    padding: 6px;
}

.margin4horizontal {
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-right: 4px;
}

.fancyorangetext {
    text-shadow: 0 0 6px orange !important;
    font-size: xx-large;
}

.leftmargin8 {
    margin-left: 8px !important;
}

.sectiontext {
    color: navy !important;
    font-size: large;
    font-weight: normal !important;
}
```

...otherwise, it's just these bootstrap classes that are being used:

```
jumbotron
row
col-md-6
col-md-12
control-label
form-control
h3
h4
btn btn-primary
btn btn-sm
```

The entire HTML for those two problematic labels (in context) is:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" name="unitsCheckboxDiv">
        <label class="sectiontext">Select a Unit</label>
        <select class="form-control, dropdown">
            @foreach (var field in units)
            {
                <option id="selItem_@(field.unit)" value="@field.unit">@field.unit</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" name="unitsCheckboxDiv">
        <div class="containerforplatypus">
            <label class="sectiontext">Select Report[s]</label>
            @foreach (var rpt in reports)
            {
                <input class="leftmargin8" id="ckbx_@(rpt.report)" type="checkbox" value="@rpt.report" />@rpt.report
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### UPDATE 2

It works now, with no change; it first worked on trying fmz's suggestion, but then I tried my previous approach again, and it now works, and even without the "!important" marker:

```
.sectiontext {
    color: navy !important;
    font-size: large;
    /*font-weight: 400 !important; <= works */
    /*font-weight: normal !important; <= works now, as does the rule below */
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: Are there any other statements acting on the labels?

Comment: Is it possible that you missed something, like a typo somewhere or a bold class with !important?

Comment: Is your `font-weight` attribute declared after the `font-size` attribute?

Comment: What you are saying doesn't make sense, because by default h4 is bolded and label is not. You must have some other css that affect that label. Can you post it?

Comment: @Zack: Yes, it is.

Comment: @Ziv: I added an update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using:

label {font-weight: 400 !important}

Also specify the font-size, as your label appears to be displaying a larger than normal font size.

Comment: I don't want all labels to be large like this; these are "special" labels, that's why I've got a CSS class for them.

Comment: I tried your approach (400), and it worked; but then I tried "normal" again, and *it* worked! Even without "!important" The only thing that changed was I went to lunch in the meantime...

Answer (score 3):

A label by default is not bold.

Try to overwrite it with:

`html label.sectiontext {
  font-weight: inherit;
}`

The html and tag name will give it some priority. If inherit doesn't work then try "normal".

Comment: I am using normal (with "!important") even).

Answer (score 2):

Can you please include a working sample of your code? (jsfiddle or such)

Without seeing an actual code sample, I'd say that the `h4` settings override your `sectiontext` class settings and you would need to add `h4 .sectiontext { font-weight: normal; }`

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to add an answer here that's not directly related to OP but took me a moment to realize when using downloaded custom font for the first time. I received a .zip file and followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53422027/how-to-use-downloaded-image-or-fontzip-file-in-css).

My font was **heavy** and I wasn't sure why I couldn't remove the bold, but if you're working with a font pack read through all the names and make sure you're using the right one in your font declaration.

```
> ls .\assets\Fonts\Raleway\ | select -Property Name

Name
----
Raleway-Black.ttf <-- I used this first
Raleway-BlackItalic.ttf
Raleway-Bold.ttf
Raleway-BoldItalic.ttf
Raleway-ExtraBold.ttf
Raleway-ExtraBoldItalic.ttf
Raleway-ExtraLight.ttf
Raleway-ExtraLightItalic.ttf
Raleway-Italic.ttf
Raleway-Light.ttf
Raleway-LightItalic.ttf
Raleway-Medium.ttf
Raleway-MediumItalic.ttf
Raleway-Regular.ttf <-- This is the one I wanted
Raleway-SemiBold.ttf
Raleway-SemiBoldItalic.ttf
Raleway-Thin.ttf
Raleway-ThinItalic.ttf
SIL Open Font License.txt
```

In this case, my font declaration looked like this in the stylesheet.

```
@font-face {
        font-family: "Raleway";
        src: url("/assets/Fonts/raleway/Raleway-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
}
```